# React-native Date Time Picker Backdrop Issue

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, datetimepicker

I'm using `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` in my react-native project.When I opened the date time picker and press the back button of android, The state is not being set again to false. Here is the code for the date time picker -

```
  <ToggleButtonForPicker DownIcon={false} onButtonPress={()=>this.setState({ showDatePicker : true})} buttonTitle={this.state.selectedDate} />
            {this.state.showDatePicker && 
                <DateTimePicker
                    value={new Date(new Date().getFullYear()-18, 1, 1)}
                    minimumDate={new Date(1900, 1, 1)}
                    maximumDate={new Date(new Date().getFullYear()-18, 1, 1)}
                    locale={"en"}
                    timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
                    modalTransparent={false}
                    animationType={"fade"}
                    androidMode={"default"}
                    placeHolderText="Date Of Birth"
                    textStyle={{ color: "black" }}
                    placeHolderTextStyle={{ opacity : 0.7}}
                    onChange={this.onDateChange}
                    disabled={false}
                    onTouchCancel = {()=>this.setState({showDatePicker : false})}
                    onCancel = {()=>this.setState({showDatePicker : false})}

                    // This is not working here (and I need this thing here so badly.)
                    onBackdropPress = {()=>this.setState({showDatePicker : false})}
                />
            }
```

When I open the date time picker and press the hardware back button, The date time picker gets close but after doing this process when I tried to type something in any TextInput of same Component, The date time picker is appearing again and again automatically.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
onButtonPress={ () => this.setState({ showDatePicker : !this.state.showDatePicker}) }
```

Comment: Still facing the same issue. I've already tried these solutions.

I'm talking about hardware back button press when date picker is open, and then try to type some thing in the TextInput of same component.

Answer (score 0):

```
onButtonPress={()=>this.setState({ showDatePicker : true})}
```

`onButtonPress` inclusive the `TextInput`

Submit more code for detailed solution